# NFS mounting wrong File System

Tags: linux, filesystems, nfs

I have followed this How To ( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo ).

My machine has a file system 30GB and other File System of 1TB mounted on /backup

As this How To says to create a /export and mount with --bind the folder you want on it, I did this:

Mounted the 1TB FS on /backup, mkdir /export, mounted --bind /backup /export.

then went to the client and mounted -nfs nfs_server:/export /nsf-backup.

but when I run df -h it says I have 30GB on /nfs-backup insted of 1TB, it is not recognizing that the 1TB FS is mounted on /backup. Am I missing something here? First time working with NFS.

```
client@host:~$ df -h
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2                    138G   20G  112G  15% /
udev                         1.4G  4.0K  1.4G   1% /dev
tmpfs                        577M  1.2M  576M   1% /run
none                         5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                         1.5G  156K  1.5G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sdb1                    597G  241G  356G  41% /extHD
nfs-server-IP:/export/backup   30G  896M   28G   4% /nfs-backup

root@nfs-server:/backup# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       30G  896M   28G   4% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            284M   12K  284M   1% /dev
tmpfs            59M  204K   59M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            295M     0  295M   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/xvdf1      985G   14G  922G   2% /backup
```

Comment: Did you do the bind mount *after* exporting /export? If so, unmount the filesystem on the client, run `exportfs -a` on the server, and mount the filesystem on the client again.

Comment: I've unmounted on the client and ran the command exportfs -a but it did not worked, still getting the 30GB FileSystem

Comment: Are you sure, on the server, that /export is a mounted filesystem? I tried `mount --bind /media/me/my-cd /export` on an Ubuntu system, and after that, `df` shows `/export` in the list of mounted filesystems. But your `df` output above doesn't include `/export`.

Comment: I did notice that also, it does not show /export as a mounted filesystem, that should be the error, but when I go to the /backup and create a test file, it appears at the /export.

Comment: Can you paste the output of `grep /export /proc/mounts` and `grep /backup /proc/mounts`? I wonder if the filesystem type of /backup for some reason makes it so it cannot be exported.

Comment: root@nfs-server:/# grep /export /proc/mounts<br/>
    /dev/xvdf1 /export ext3 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0

Comment: root@nfs-server:/# grep /backup /proc/mounts
/dev/xvdf1 /backup ext3 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0

Comment: Just noticed that your client is mounting server:/export/backup. Do you want it to mount server:/export instead? What mount point is listed in the server's `/etc/exports` file?

Comment: About the mount point for the client I've change it to server:/export. the /etc/exports: /export       client-IP(rw,insecure,no_subtree_check,async)

Comment: If you still have the problem after changing the mount point on the client, I'm afraid I'm out of ideas. Please edit the question to include the current output of `df` on the client, and the lines of the server's `/etc/exports`, `/etc/fstab`, and `/proc/mounts` that contain `/export`.

Comment: on server mount /dev/xvdf1  on /export/backup, then exportfs -a ; then mount on client.

Answer (score 1):

I had read about some cases in which the `nohide` option is needed (in the client side) in order to make the NFS clients capable of seeing binded folder/partitions in the server. I've never tried this option, but maybe you should take a [look](http://linux.die.net/man/5/exports).

As a short resolution, i would export directly the 1TB FS. Whether mounting it directly over the `/exports` (`mount /dev/hdX /exports -t <fs-type>`), or mounting it in another location and exporting it. The detail is that you will need to add in your NFS configuration file `/etc/exports` the option [`crossmnt`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/exports) and reload the service with `exportfs -r`.